# Semiadditivity and dualizability of 2

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

**Short version**: Let (C, ⊗, 1) be a locally presentable closed symmetric monoidal category with a zero object, and write 2 = 1 ∐ 1.  Suppose the object 2 has a dual.  Does it follow that C is a category with biproducts?

**Longer version, with motivation**: Let (C, ⊗, 1) be a locally presentable closed symmetric monoidal category.  If you don't know what "locally presentable" means, you can replace these conditions with "complete and cocomplete symmetric monoidal category in which ⊗ commutes with colimits in each variable".  Familiar examples include (Set, ×, •), (Set<sub>*</sub>, ∧, S<sup>0</sup>) (the category of pointed sets with the smash product), and (Ab, ⊗, ℤ).  Any such category C has a unique "unit" functor F<sub>C</sub> : Set → C preserving colimits and the unit object: the set S is sent to the coproduct in C of S copies of 1.  For a nonnegative integer n, let me also write n for the image under this functor of the n-element set.  For instance, 0 represents the initial object of C.

A *dual* for an object X of C is another object X<sup>*</sup> together with maps 1 → X ⊗ X<sup>*</sup> and X<sup>*</sup> ⊗ X → 1 which satisfy the triangular identities; see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_object) for more details.  The data of X<sup>*</sup> together with these maps is unique up to unique isomorphism if it exists, so it makes sense to ask whether an object has a dual or not.

I'm interested in the relationship between which objects in the image of F<sub>C</sub> have duals and the existence of more familiar structures on C.  In our examples,

- C = Set: Only 1 has a dual.
- C = Set<sub>*</sub>: Only 1 and 0 = • have duals.
- C = Ab: n has a dual for any nonnegative integer n.

It's easy to show that 1 is always its own dual, and slightly less trivially, that 0 has a dual iff 0 is also a final object, i.e., C has a zero object, or equivalently C is enriched in Set<sub>*</sub>.  Moreover, if C is [semiadditive](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12410/terminology-is-there-a-name-for-a-category-with-biproducts/12419#12419), i.e., enriched in commutative monoids, or equivalently has biproducts, then n has a dual (in fact, n is its own dual) for every nonnegative integer n.  Conversely, if 0 has a dual, so that C is pointed, and 2 also has a dual, then there is a canonical map 2 = 1 ∐ 1 → 1 × 1 = 2<sup>*</sup>.  My question, then, is: is this map is always an isomorphism?  Or, could it happen that 2<sup>*</sup> exists but is not isomorphic to 2 via this map?

Comment: Why do you know $1\times 1=2^*$ when $2^*$ and $0^*$ exist?

Comment: Because Hom(X, 2*) = Hom(2 ⊗ X, 1) = Hom(X ∐ X, 1) = Hom(X, 1) × Hom(X, 1) = Hom(X, 1 × 1).

Answer (score 12):

It is true that in a cosmos $\mathcal{V}$ (= a complete and cocomplete symmetric monoidal closed category) with zero object where $2$ has a dual, the canonical map $1+1 \rightarrow 1\times 1$ is invertible. In other words, you don't even need to assume that $\mathcal{V}$ is locally presentable. I think that this implies that the cosmos in question is semiadditive, which in turn implies that coproducts/products are biproducts (the only thing one needs to observe is that $C\otimes 1\times 1 \cong C\times C$, which follows from the fact that $1\times 1$ is the dual of $1+1$).

Proving this is a bit too involved for MO (because there is no good way of drawing string diagrams here). I have typed up an argument, which can be found [here](http://homepages.uni-regensburg.de/~scd37703/downloads/notes/semiadditive.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180202062936/http://homepages.uni-regensburg.de/~scd37703/downloads/notes/semiadditive.pdf)). I first prove that an autonomous symmetric monoidal category (autonomous means that all objects have duals) where the coproduct $1+1$ exists is semiadditive.

I can try to give some intuition for the argument in question. The key idea is that one wants to construct a diagonal map $1 \rightarrow 1+1$. The way to do this was inspired by the following paper:

André Joyal, Ross Street and Dominic Verity (1996). Traced monoidal categories. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society,   119 , pp 447-468
[doi:10.1017/S0305004100074338](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100074338)

In my writeup, this "diagonal map" is the map $1\rightarrow 1+1$ in the string diagrams which is built out of a "loop" and the map $1+1 \rightarrow (1+1) \otimes (1+1)$ which I called $h$. From the formula given in the introduction of the paper by Joyal, Street and Verity it follows that my construction does indeed give the diagonal map in the case where $\mathcal{V}$ is the cosmos of vector spaces over some field.

Edit: updated expired link.

Comment: For anyone encountering this question now, this result was written up as [When coproducts are biproducts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01669) (Garner–Schäppi).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A proof is recorded in Prop 1.4.6 and Rmk 1.4.7 of my thesis [Free duals and a new universal property for stable equivariant homotopy theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.04207.pdf#page=12), though as Daniel's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21307) indicates, the experts were aware of this much earlier. It also appears that I upvoted at some point, so I think I was aware of Daniel's answer here when I wrote my thesis.